# What data is required and available for persistant http connections

Tags: python, http, streaming, persist

I'm trying to send a stream of images across http using a "persistent" connection. I have keep-alive in the header and so does the client (firefox) but I dont know how to send the second request or how to wrap it.

I've read the rfc. I've also wiresharked the connection while looking at a streaming service just like the one I'm trying to duplicate. I dont see any http messages going back and forth as the data is streamed (mjpg streamer)

So My question is this, what is required to send back to client in a http persistent connection ? If I just send fully formed http responses or just jpg data the client disconnects. If I wait for the client to send more data before sending the second image the client never sends anything.

```
import socket
import sys
import time
import binascii
from thread import *

HOST = ''   # Symbolic name meaning all available interfaces
PORT = 9998 # Arbitrary non-privileged port

in_file = open("picture.jpg", "rb") # opening for [r]eading as [b]inary
testJpg = in_file.read() # if you only wanted to read 512 bytes, do .read(512)
in_file.close()

in_file = open("picture2.jpg", "rb") # opening for [r]eading as [b]inary
testJpg2 = in_file.read() # if you only wanted to read 512 bytes, do .read(512)
in_file.close()

OddNumber = 0

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

#Bind socket to local host and port
try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Bind failed. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + ' Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()

print 'Socket bind complete'

#Start listening on socket
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

#Function for handling connections. This will be used to create threads
def clientthread(conn):
    global OddNumber, testJpg, testJpg2
    OddNumber = 0

    # get data from the client (assume its a http get request)
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    print("\r\n Got1: "+str(len(data)))
    #time.sleep(.05)
    while OddNumber < 30:


        # create a new reply 
        reply = "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n"
        reply += "Server: MJPG-Streamer/0.2\r\n"
        reply += "Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0\r\n"
        reply += "Pragma: no-cache\r\n"
        reply += "Content-type: image/jpeg\r\n"
        # add in the content len
        if OddNumber % 2 == 0:
            reply += "Content-Length: "+str(len(testJpg))+"\r\n"
        else:
            reply += "Content-Length: "+str(len(testJpg2))+"\r\n"
        # add the keep alive portion
        reply += "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n"
        # I think we need this
        reply += "\r\n"

        # I use this toggle to switch between different images so if it does "stream" i'll be able to see it 
        # flipping these images
        if OddNumber % 2 == 0:
            reply += testJpg
        else:
            reply += testJpg2

        # after the image
        reply += "\r\n"


        conn.sendall(reply)
        OddNumber += 1
        print("\r\n OddNum: "+str(OddNumber))
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        print("\r\n Got1: "+str(len(data)))
        print(str(data))
        #time.sleep(.05)

    #came out of loop
    conn.close()

#now keep talking with the client
while 1:
    #wait to accept a connection - blocking call
    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connected with ' + addr[0] + ':' + str(addr[1])

    #start new thread takes 1st argument as a function name to be run, second is the tuple of arguments to the function.
    start_new_thread(clientthread ,(conn,))

s.close()
```

Apart from that I'm wondering if the persistent connection will even work for me. I'm developing a embedded device that is hosting the images, similar to a ipcamera. But I need to be able to send different URL's back to the device while it is sending me images. Is this possible on the same port ?

Someone requested I show whats in my http response. It is what you see in the python script. Its a valid http response and it works fine if I set 
Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n"
to 
Connection: close\r\n"

I guess my question is, what do you have to do in a persistent connection. Will the client send more "get" requests or is the server expected to stream some data ? At least firefox only sends one "get" request and then I send the response with a image but then what has to happen next to keep it going ?

Thanks for all the help so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's because you use the same socket object in both client and server. Can you separate your code into two files? One file for server and the other for client (means your clientthread function).

In HTTP, when client get an HTTP response with 'keep-alive', it will hold TCP connection no matter what kinds of data you send.

Comment: Thanks for your response !Actually my client is "firefox" browser. I think my issue lies in what to send back in a persistent connection. I have a open socket where I get the first "get" request, I send back a valid response, but then what do I do. If I send another page (without a request) the client (firefox) closes the socket.

Comment: @user1202605 I guess there may be something wrong with your http response header. Could you show us in by updating your question?